# How to merge similar columns into a single dictionary column in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert a dataframe that has similar naming convention into a single `json` format column.

Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : 1,
                  'userName' : 'john',
                  'productlist0.name' : 'shoe',
                  'productlist0.price' : 45.89,
                  'productlist0.brand' : 'nike',
                  'productlist1.name' : 'jeans',
                  'productlist1.price' : 19.45,
                  'productlist1.brand' : 'howes',
                  'productlist2.name' : 'watch',
                  'productlist2.price' : 60.0,
                  'productlist2.brand' : 'fossil'
                  }, index = [0])
```

So we have bunch of columns starting with `productlist` and that share the column names after the period.

I need to covert these columns into below `json` format:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
                  {'id' : 1,
                   'userName' : 'john',
                   'productlist' : '''[{'name' : 'shoe', 'price' : 45.89, 'brand' : 'nike'},
                                   {'name' : 'jeans', 'price' : 19.45, 'brand' : 'howes'},
                                   {'name' : 'watch', 'price' : 60.0, 'brand' : 'fossil'}]'''
                   }, index = [0]
                    )

df1
id  userName    productlist
0   1   john    [{'name' : 'shoe', 'price' : 45.89, 'brand' : 'nike'}, {'name' : 'jeans', 'price' : 19.45, 'brand' : 'howes'}, {'name' : 'watch', 'price' : 60.0, 'brand' : 'fossil'}]
```

I tried to use the `stack` approach and got here:

```
df.filter(regex = '^productlist').rename(columns = lambda x : re.sub(r'productlist\d\.', '', x)).stack().reset_index().\
            groupby(['level_0', 'level_1'])[0].agg(dict)

level_0  level_1
0        brand      {2: 'nike', 5: 'howes', 8: 'fossil'}
         name        {0: 'shoe', 3: 'jeans', 6: 'watch'}
         price             {1: 45.89, 4: 19.45, 7: 60.0}
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

But I am not sure how to proceed from here. Could someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex="^productlist\d+.").T
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a[0], a[1]) for a in df1.index.str.split(".")])
product_values = df1.unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1).to_dict("records")
df1 = pd.concat(
    [
        df[["id", "userName"]],
        pd.DataFrame({"productlist": [product_values]}, index=[0]),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

First get `productlist` columns. Then reindex with `(productlist, key)` format and unstack and get a dict in the form of "records" out of it. That will be your list of dicts. Use that to create a new dataframe with column "productlist" and then concat it to original df without `productlist\d+.` columns

print(df1):

```
   id userName                                        productlist
0   1     john  [{'brand': 'nike', 'name': 'shoe', 'price': 45...
```

Comment: When I am trying in my actual data, I am getting this error : `DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.` could you please let me know the reason. Data is not much different my sample data above

Comment: Not sure if you already solved your problem, but that error might be coming from second line where you are assigning multiindex and if you duplicate column names in your original dataframe.